# How can I prevent my app from downgrading from TLSv1.2 on iOS 8?

Tags: ios, secure-transport

I am trying to restrict my app from communicating with a server that is running any version of TLS prior to 1.2. From the docs, it appears that I should be able to do this by calling `SSLSetProtocolVersionMin`, so I have done that:

```
SSLContextRef context = SSLCreateContext(NULL, kSSLClientSide, kSSLStreamType);
SSLSetProtocolVersionMax(context, kTLSProtocol12);
SSLSetProtocolVersionMin(context, kTLSProtocol12);
```

I have verified that the call to `SSLSetProtocolVersionMin` does not return an error, but I am still able to connect to servers that negotiate down to SSLv3.

`SSLSetProtocolVersionMax` appears to work correctly, as when I set it to TLSv1.1 and the server to TLSv1.2 only, I cannot connect to the server.

It appears that this works as expected on iOS 9. Does anybody know if this is not supported in iOS 8, or if there are other steps I need to take?

Comment: Might be a bug in iOS 8. I'd try to workaround it by allowing only strong ciphers (see `SSLSetEnabledCiphers`) used by TLSv1.2 – you can get a list from ATS specs. Also there's a `SSLSetSessionStrengthPolicy` function, but it seems to be deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure iOS to only connect to servers meeting a minimum TLS version using Apple's new Application Transport Security in iOS 9.

You can add code like the following to your Info.plist file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>mydomain.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>1.2<string/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

You can take a look at the [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2015/?id=711).

EDIT:

I see you added to your question to state that you need to accomplish this on iOS 8, which does not have ATS. But hopefully this answer will help those using iOS 9 and that need to do this, since the original question did not include this limitation.